# Recommended way to use a setting file to initialize OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, configuration

I am new to OpenLayers. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to have a configuration file for the map I am creating.

For example, I am creating a map with the following style :

```
    var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(
                        {
                            pointRadius: 10,
                            fillColor: "yellow",
                            strokeColor:"#0500bd", 
                            strokeWidth:2,
                            fillOpacity:0.4,
                            labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
                            labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
                            labelAlign: "${align}"
                        });
```

I would like to have the `pointRadius` and `fillColor` in a config file so I don't have to modify my source code but just the config file.

Shall I create a JS file; config.js with the following content:

```
      var configMap = {
         pointRadius: 10,
         fillColor: "yellow"
      }
```

And then, in my other JS that create the style, does:

```
    var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(
    {
        pointRadius: configMap.pointRadius,
            fillColor: configMap.fillColor,
        strokeColor:"#0500bd", 
        strokeWidth:2,
        fillOpacity:0.4,
                    labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
            labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
        labelAlign: "${align}"
    });
```

What is recommended?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? I would be interested